# javascript function is not working correctly in cakephp 2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, cakephp-2.9

I am using cakephp 2.9.9, I want to use a simple jquery function and included in default.ctp, but it is not working as expected. Details are as follows:

1.I have downloaded the JQuery Library jquery-3.2.1.js, my javascript file name is script.js, I kept these two files in /app/webroot/js folder.

2.In my default.ctp file I have added the following lines -

```
echo $this->Html->script('jquery-3.2.1');
echo $this->Html->script('script');
echo $scripts_for_layout;
```

3.I want to change style of my navigation menu based on the current active link. My script.js file is as follows -

```
(function(){

    console.log(1); //this can be seen on console
    $("#nav a").on("click", function(e){
        console.log(2); // this cannot be seen on console
        $("#nav a").removeClass('active');
        $(e.currentTarget).addClass('active');
    });
})();
```

4.When I open my page, the page calls the script file (as 1 is executed on console) but it is not calling the .on() function of jquery. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: check your browser console and see you have any error there?

Comment: You are using bootstrap..

Comment: no there is no error displaying on the console - @Alive to Die

Comment: no, I am not using bootstrap - @ChandraKumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for this problem. Instead of using jquery .on() function, I am changing the css based on the current URL. My code is as follows-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var nav = document.getElementById('nav');
var anchor = nav.getElementsByTagName('a');
var current = location.href;
for (var i = 0; i < anchor.length; i++) {
    if(anchor[i].href == current) {
        anchor[i].className = "active";
    }
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

It might be caused by the following:

1. Check that you add jQuery **before** the script that uses it. Instead
   of `console.log(1)` try to output in the console `console.log($)`
   and make sure that Jquery is loaded.
2. Usually using JQuery we put our code inside `ready()` function like `$(document).ready(function() { // code goes here });`
3. Check that selector `#nav a` does actually exist on the page.
       Maybe it should be `nav a`?
4. If you use things like `async/defer` on script tags, make sure
       that you use `defer` (it preserves the order of the scripts) or
       remove it all and load script synchronously.
5. It is rather silly suggestion but have you actually clicked on
       links? Because you write "it is not calling the .on() function of
       jquery". By the way, you do not prevent the default behaviour (at
       least in the piece of code you shared), so even if everything is ok
       with Jquery and your code, a new page will be loaded and you will
       not see the style of the links changed on the current page. You have
       to use `e.preventDefault()` inside click handler - notice that in such case you will get your code applied, but a new page will not be loaded by default - `e.preventDefault()` cancels it. Instead, you have to load new content through AJAX or save the link into a variable and open new page in a new/current tab with JS like `document.location.assign = "link-to-a-new-page"` later.

It is hard to say more since you shared only tiny portion of your code.